# KDB+\q: How to fill regularly spaced time series?

Tags: kdb

I am trying to implement .ml.filltab[] located [here](https://code.kx.com/v2/ml/toolkit/utilities/preproc/) on a table of timeseries data composed of regularly interspaced temporal aggregations i.e.:

```
second     |  amount price 
-----------|----------------
02:46:01   |  54     9953.5
02:46:04   |  150          
02:46:05   |         9954.5
```

Applying the .ml.filltab[] function does not update the index so the table incorrectly fills values without the appropriate index.
i.e.

```
second     |  amount price 
-----------|----------------
02:46:01   |  54     9953.5
02:46:04   |  150    9953.5    
02:46:05   |  150    9953.5
```

As opposed to correctly filling in the index as follows:

```
second     |  amount price 
-----------|----------------
02:46:01   |  54     9953.5
02:46:02   |  54     9953.5
02:46:03   |  54     9953.5
02:46:04   |  150    9953.5    
02:46:05   |  150    9954.5
```

In addition to the above It also requires a column by which to group the data i.e. a `sym column which is unnecessary when only aggregating a single series.

How does one run a fill forward operation on a table accounting for missing index?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way of doing this would be to create a secondary empty table with the same schema where the second column has all of the missing time points. To do this create a list of all the times you are interested in. One way of doing this would be to take the first and last element and do the following:

```
q)f:exec first second from t
q)f
02:46:01
q)l:exec last second from t
q)l
02:46:05
q)s:f+`second$til 1+`long$l-f
q)s
02:46:01 02:46:02 02:46:03 02:46:04 02:46:05
```

Note that the second type needed to be casted to a long type to work with the til function, then cast back to a second type. Also we add 1 to ensure the last time (`02:46:05`) is not missed out.

We can create an empty table with the same schema by doing the following:

```
q)et:select by second:s from 0#t
q)et
second  | amount price
--------| ------------
02:46:01|
02:46:02|
02:46:03|
02:46:04|
02:46:05|
```

The `0#` is a quick way of creating an empty table with the same schema as the original table `t`. Now an [lj](https://code.kx.com//v2/ref/lj/) can be used to merge the two tables together, and [fills](https://code.kx.com//v2/ref/fill/#fills) will then forward fill in any nulls:

```
q)et lj t
second  | amount price
--------| -------------
02:46:01| 54     9953.5
02:46:02|
02:46:03|
02:46:04| 150
02:46:05|        9954.5
q)fills et lj t
second  | amount price
--------| -------------
02:46:01| 54     9953.5
02:46:02| 54     9953.5
02:46:03| 54     9953.5
02:46:04| 150    9953.5
02:46:05| 150    9954.5
```

Answer (score 4):

You really have two separate steps here: filling null values in your table, and generating a time series with regularly spaced intervals from your table.

You already have the means to fill in null values. To generate a time series you can use the [as-of join](https://code.kx.com/v2/ref/aj/) function.

Given your (already filled) table

```
q)show t:([second:02:46:01 02:46:04 02:46:05]amount:45 150 150;price:9953.5 9953.5 9954.5)
second  | amount price
--------| -------------
02:46:01| 45     9953.5
02:46:04| 150    9953.5
02:46:05| 150    9954.5
```

you can generate a time series by first defining an auxiliary table with the desired sample times

```
q)show ts:([]second:02:46:01+til 5)
second
--------
02:46:01
02:46:02
02:46:03
02:46:04
02:46:05
```

and then as-of joining these two tables

```
q)aj[`second;ts;t]
second   amount price
----------------------
02:46:01 45     9953.5
02:46:02 45     9953.5
02:46:03 45     9953.5
02:46:04 150    9953.5
02:46:05 150    9954.5
```

You can easily extend this method to generate such time series when your table contains multiple instruments.